# Changing definitions in the class file

Tags: class-options

I am relatively new to Latex and don't know the deeper commands yet. For my Msc thesis I downloaded a template published by the Faculty, however they have changed some regulations and have yet to update their latex template.

Basically, the new regulations require 1.5/double space. Easy enough to do with

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

But I get some errors which says `\spacing` has already been defined. So I look into the class file of the template and I find:

```
\newcommand{\spacing}[1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}%
  \large\normalsize}
```

This command in being used in the following places:

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{saving}}{\spacing{1}}{\spacing{2}}}
```

and

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{saving}} {%
  \setlength {\topmargin}{0.0in}
  \setlength {\textheight}{\paperheight-2.5in}
  \setlength {\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
  \setlength {\evensidemargin}{0.0in}
  \setlength {\textwidth}{\paperwidth-2in}
  \spacing{1}
  } {%
  \setlength {\topmargin}{0.65in}
  \setlength {\textheight}{\paperheight-3.05in}
  \setlength {\oddsidemargin}{0.6in}
  \setlength {\evensidemargin}{0.1in}
  \setlength {\textwidth}{\paperwidth-2.65in}
  \setlength {\footskip}{0.3in}
  \spacing{2}
  \renewenvironment{quote}{\oldquote\spacing{1}}%
       {\oldendquote\spacing{2}}
  \renewenvironment{quotation}{\oldquotation\spacing{1}}%
       {\oldendquotation\spacing{2}}
  \renewenvironment{verse}{\oldverse\spacing{1}}%
       {\oldendverse\spacing{2}}}
```

And some other (probably irrelevant) sections.

My question is that **can I just rename this command something else** and replace it everywhere it shows up in the class file? This way it won't clash with `setspace` package. Additionally, do I have to somehow recompile the class file or register it with latex?

Comment: Before changing anything in the class file, check the license, you may not be allowed to make changes.

Comment: @Johannes_B I will keep that in mind. My department buddy's thesis actually got rejected and they told him make several revisions. I am not sure how one would go about making those revisions without editing the class file though.

Comment: What/Who is providing the template? If it is an *official* template, poke the guys responsible. If it is just some stuff handed over from one year to the next year of students .... Wanna be a LaTeX-class-file-maintainer? ;-)

Comment: I am fairly certain it was developed by a student at some point. Since the official university faculty website has no mention of it. I pasted the CTAN link below. After I finish my thesis, I do plan on cleaning up the class file (and learning some deep latex). Hopefully I can submit my work to the faculty and they can start using it as the official template.

Comment: Just saw the link: I'd suggest to write Diane a polite email referring to this question and asking her to update to match the current specs. The introduction is quite clear: You are responsible. Rename the class file to e.g. `masfenix.cls`, add a comment with your name and date inside and *start hacking*.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. Last question: So a latex template is purely defined by its class file? Is a class file merely commands to keep the actual document cleaner, and that all the commands from the class file can actually be put in the .tex file itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27576/discussion-between-johannes-b-and-masfenix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rename the command if you replace the name everywhere in the class *and* in every other file linked to your thesis.

For your second question, I assume that you refer to the class locally and that you have a private copy. No, you don't have to recompile the class or register it anywhere, just save it.

Comment: Is there a better solution? I am not sure if there are other files linked to my thesis. I downloaded the template from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/york-thesis?lang=en

Would it be better to change something in the `setspace` package instead?

Comment: @masfenix -- `setspace` is posted on ctan and is included in tex live.  it has *much* wider distribution than any thesis class, so it would be a *very bad idea* to modify it, especially without a name change.

Comment: Okay thanks. I think the best bet would be just to replace the definition in the class file.